# Debug not starting on TIBCO Business Works 6 (Eclipse-based)

Tags: eclipse, tibco, businessworks

I'm trying to debug Business Works 6 (which is eclipse based) application.

Here is the log from the console:

```
"
13:01:54.308 INFO  [Start Level Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.thor.frwk - TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks version 6.2.1, build V18, 2015-03-13
13:01:56.853 INFO  [Start Level Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Deployer - Started by BusinessStudio.

<>@BWEclipseAppNode> 13:02:00.274 INFO  [Start Level Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.bw.frwk.engine.BWEngine - TIBCO-BW-FRWK-300002: BW Engine [Main] started successfully.
13:02:00.450 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Deployer - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300001: Started OSGi Framework of AppNode [BWEclipseAppNode] in AppSpace [BWEclipseAppSpace] of Domain [BWEclipseDomain]
13:02:00.568 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300018: Deploying BW Application [tibco.infrastructure.services.dbsoa.application:1.0].
13:02:00.692 INFO  [Thread-36] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300019: BW Application [tibco.infrastructure.services.dbsoa.application:1.0] is impaired.
13:02:00.697 INFO  [Framework Event Dispatcher] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - Started by BusinessStudio, ignoring .enabled settings.
!SESSION 2015-06-04 13:01:50.526 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/Users/ohadav/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/BWApplication/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-04 13:02:01.104
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2015-06-04 13:02:01.104
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../shared/com.tibco.bw.tpcl.org.hyperic.sigar_1.6.5.001/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.tibco.bw.tpcl.org.hyperic.sigar 2 0 2015-06-04 13:02:01.104
!MESSAGE Missing native code match sigar-x86-winnt.dll; processor=x86; osname=WindowsServer2000; osname=WindowsServer2003; osname=WindowsNT; osname=WindowsXP; osname=WindowsVista; osname=Windows7; osname=WindowsServer2008; osname=Win32, sigar-amd64-winnt.dll; processor=x86-64; osname=WindowsVista; osname=Windows7; osname=WindowsServer2008; osname=WindowsServer2003; osname=Windows Server 2012 R2; osname=Windows Server 2012; osname=WindowsServer2012; osname=WindowsServer2012R2, libsigar-amd64-linux.so; processor=x86-64; osname=Linux, libsigar-ia64-linux.so; processor=ia64w; osname=Linux, libsigar-ppc-linux.so; libsigar-ppc64-linux.so; processor=powerpc; osname=Linux, libsigar-s390x-linux.so; processor=s390x; osname=Linux, libsigar-x86-linux.so; processor=x86; osname=Linux, libsigar-amd64-freebsd-6.so; processor=x86-64; osname=FreeBSD, libsigar-x86-freebsd-5.so; libsigar-x86-freebsd-6.so; processor=x86; osname=FreeBSD, libsigar-amd64-solaris.so; processor=x86-64; osname=Solaris, libsigar-sparc-solaris.so; processor=sparc; osname=Solaris, libsigar-sparc64-solaris.so; processor=sparcv9; osname=Solaris, libsigar-x86-solaris.so; processor=x86; osname=Solaris, libsigar-universal-macosx.dylib; processor=x86; processor=powerpc; osname=MacOSX, libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib; processor=x86-64; processor=powerpc; osname=MacOSX, libsigar-ppc64-aix-5.so; processor=powerpc; osname=AIX, libsigar-ppc-aix-5.so; processor=powerpc; osname=AIX, libsigar-ia64-hpux-11.sl; processor=ia64w; osname=HPUX, libsigar-pa-hpux-11.sl; processor=parisc; osname=HPUX.
13:02:02.829 INFO  [Job_Executor0] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300021: All Application dependencies are resolved for Application [tibco.infrastructure.services.dbsoa.application:1.0]
13:02:04.270 INFO  [Thread-43] com.tibco.thor.frwk.Application - TIBCO-THOR-FRWK-300019: BW Application [tibco.infrastructure.services.dbsoa.application:1.0] is impaired.
"
```

My projects doesn't contain any errors/warnings.
Can someone assist ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue:
AMBW-16997 Summary: When running an ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks application on
Microsoft Windows 2012, an error message,
com.tibco.bw.tpcl.org.hyperic.sigar, is thrown during startup.
Workaround: None.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Windows 8.1 after it worked for a while.

You need to add your specific runtime environment (OS) by editing

```
[TIBCO_HOME]\bw\6.2\system\shared\com.tibco.bw.tpcl.org.hyperic.sigar_1.6.5.001\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF**
```

Under Bundle-NativeCode add a `osname="YourOperatingSystemAlias"` after the appropriate lib-file specification. For me it did `osname="Windows 8.1"` right after `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll`.

This workaround is dirty, so watch out.